# Существую ли уже готовые библиотеки текстовых редакторов?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сверху 3 кнопки при нажатии на нее она остается подсвечена, при этом тип грифта должен измениться.

Comment: любой текстовый редактор на js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться этим кодом c использованием библиотеки `Quill`
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJzXrv

```
var quill = new Quill('#editor-container', {
  modules: {
    toolbar: [
      ['bold', 'italic', 'underline']
    ]
  },
  placeholder: 'Compose an epic...',
  theme: 'snow'  // or 'bubble'
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]